# Can't stack views correctly in a NSClipView

Tags: swift, nsview, nsclipview

I'm getting mad at this code because it just shows the last view (in it's correct position) and it forgets to paint the others...

```
// Gets a stack of devices
let volumes = getDevices()
var index = 0
for device in volumes {
    let volume = devicePrototype
    // devicePrototype it's a custom view
    volume?.setName(name: device.name) // setting the label for the name
    volume?.setIcon(icon: device.icon) // setting the image for the icon
    // Setting the position of the view (width = 600, height = 105)
    // and all the views have the same size.
    volume?.layer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: index * 105, width: 600, height: 105)
    // Adding the view to the NSClipView (Here's the problem :P)
    devicesStack.addSubview(volume!)
    index += 1
}
```

Can you help me find the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating only one view (device) and modifying the same through the loop. You are referencing same `devicePrototype` object repeatedly and changing the properties only. Please check that.

Try to initialize a new object in each iteration,

```
let volume = DevicePrototype()
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because I created the interface using a custom view in the interface builder and I connected its labels and image views to its own class using an outlet. So the point is: if I initialize just the class, I won't be able to use the Interface : ( and my solution was to crate an outlet from the custom view in the app delegate (named devicePrototype) so I could create instances like this one... How do I create multiple instances of something build in the interface builder?

Comment: Create custom view classes and use its instances. You can connect the classes to your interface builder views.